# How can I get a correct frame of view before viewDidAppear in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios10

I built a view in an xib, but the frame I get before `viewDidAppear` is `{0,0,1000,1000}`. It's not what I want. I had set AutoLayout for the view.

Why has this happened, and how can I get the correct frame before `viewDidAppear`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization works in this order:

1. loadView
2. viewDidLoad
3. viewWillAppear
4. viewWillLayoutSubviews
5. viewDidLayoutSubviews
6. viewDidAppear

The correct frame is available once the layout calculation has been completed. The layout calculation starts before step 4 and ends after step 5. So `viewDidAppear` is the earliest step where the frame has been calculated.

So I'm afraid you can't get it earlier than that. You will have to move the relevant code to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: very helpful , but if I want get the right frame after load xib immediately，is there any way to get it? some say call `view.setNeedsLayout()` and `view.layoutIfNeeded()` , but don't work for me . I want use the xib view to be my collectionView header. and the height is base on the screen width.

Comment: I think the trick with `view.setNeedsLayout()` and `view.layoutIfNeeded()` worked in earlier iOS version. But as far as I know, it simply not possible anymore to get computed frame size earlier than in `viewDidAppear`. You'll have to find a different approach to achieve your goals.